# Titanium Android application doesn't restart after being sent to the background and recommended fixes aren't working

Tags: android, android-activity, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

I'm using TItanium SDK 3.1.3 and my project is made in Alloy 1.0, the problem I'm experiencing has been reported in the past but even when I try to use the recommended fixes for it, it just won't work.
I've seen [this](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-1911) and [this](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-9229) tickets, so far both solutions, using the property

```
<property name="ti.android.root.reappears.restart" type="bool">true</property>
```

and the property

```
android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
```

on my tiapp.xml doesn't seem to work at all.
This is my tiapp.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ti:app xmlns:ti="http://ti.appcelerator.org">
    <id>com.nenvo.inTeamAlloy</id>
    <name>inTeamAlloy</name>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <publisher></publisher>
    <url>http://nenvo.com</url>
    <description>not specified</description>
    <copyright></copyright>
    <icon>appicon.png</icon>
    <persistent-wifi>false</persistent-wifi>
    <prerendered-icon>false</prerendered-icon>
    <statusbar-style>default</statusbar-style>
    <statusbar-hidden>false</statusbar-hidden>
    <fullscreen>false</fullscreen>
    <navbar-hidden>true</navbar-hidden>
    <analytics>true</analytics>
    <guid>c0d02147-bb42-4e9c-b29d-8c4686269836</guid>
    <property name="ti.ui.defaultunit" type="string">system</property>
    <property name="ti.android.threadstacksize" type="int">81920</property>
    <property name="ti.android.bug2373.finishfalseroot" type="bool">true</property>
    <!-- <property name="ti.android.root.reappears.restart" type="bool">true</property> -->
    <property name="ti.android.root.reappears.restart" type="bool">true</property> 

    <iphone>
        <orientations device="iphone">
            <orientation>Ti.UI.PORTRAIT</orientation>
        </orientations>
        <orientations device="ipad">
            <orientation>Ti.UI.PORTRAIT</orientation>
            <orientation>Ti.UI.UPSIDE_PORTRAIT</orientation>
            <orientation>Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_LEFT</orientation>
            <orientation>Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_RIGHT</orientation>
        </orientations>
    </iphone>
    <android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <tool-api-level>17</tool-api-level>
        <manifest android:installLocation="auto" >
             <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>
            <application android:largeHeap="true" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:theme="@style/Theme.MyTheme">

                <!-- TI_APPLICATION -->
                <activity android:name=".InteamalloyActivity"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true" 
                android:label="inTeamAlloy"  android:theme="@style/Theme.Titanium" 
                android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"><!-- android:theme="@style/Theme.Titanium" -->
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                    </intent-filter>
                </activity>

                <activity
                android:name="ti.modules.titanium.media.TiCameraActivity"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
                />

                <activity android:name="org.appcelerator.titanium.TiActivity"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                android:configChanges="keyboardHidden" />

                <activity android:name="org.appcelerator.titanium.TiTranslucentActivity"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />

                <activity android:name="ti.modules.titanium.ui.android.TiPreferencesActivity"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"/>

            </application>
        </manifest>
    </android>
    <mobileweb>
        <precache/>
        <splash>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <inline-css-images>true</inline-css-images>
        </splash>
        <theme>default</theme>
    </mobileweb>
    <modules>
        <module platform="android" version="2.3.2">ti.urbanairship</module>
        <module platform="android" version="0.1">net.iamyellow.tiws</module>
    </modules>
    <deployment-targets>
        <target device="android">true</target>
        <target device="blackberry">false</target>
        <target device="ipad">false</target>
        <target device="iphone">true</target>
        <target device="mobileweb">false</target>
        <target device="tizen">false</target>
    </deployment-targets>
    <sdk-version>3.1.3.GA</sdk-version>
    <plugins>
        <plugin version="1.0">ti.alloy</plugin>
    </plugins>
    <property name="ti.deploytype">development</property>
</ti:app>
```

What are my options in this matter? Is there a workaround for an Alloy project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging through the [Android Activity documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#always), I tried a different property in my root Activity:

```
<activity android:name=".InteamalloyActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true" <!-- This property -->
    android:label="inTeamAlloy"  
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Titanium" 
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

With the **clearTaskOnLaunch** property, according to the documentation:

> Whether or not all activities will be removed from the task, except
>   for the root activity, whenever it is re-launched from the home screen
>   — "true" if the task is always stripped down to its root activity, and
>   "false" if not. The default value is "false". This attribute is
>   meaningful only for activities that start a new task (the root
>   activity); it's ignored for all other activities in the task. When the
>   value is "true", every time users start the task again, they are
>   brought to its root activity regardless of what they were last doing
>   in the task and regardless of whether they used the Back or Home
>   button to leave it. When the value is "false", the task may be cleared
>   of activities in some situations (see the alwaysRetainTaskState
>   attribute), but not always.
>
> Suppose, for example, that someone launches activity P from the home
>   screen, and from there goes to activity Q. The user next presses Home,
>   and then returns to activity P. Normally, the user would see activity
>   Q, since that is what they were last doing in P's task. However, if P
>   set this flag to "true", all of the activities on top of it (Q in this
>   case) were removed when the user pressed Home and the task went to the
>   background. So the user sees only P when returning to the task.
>
> If this attribute and allowTaskReparenting are both "true", any
>   activities that can be re-parented are moved to the task they share an
>   affinity with; the remaining activities are then dropped, as described
>   above.

With this, when the root activity is the one being active when the application is sent to the background, the application will restart after the task related to the root activity is killed by the operative system. While this is not the optimal and most desired behaviour in an app, it certainly is the way to go when using Titanium.